# count number of characters in a list python

Tags: python

I am beginner looking for some help. I am trying to write a python program that will return a list, from a .txt file. showing the number of words with various character lengths. For example, "in list a there are five words with three or less characters."

Here is what I have so far:

```
def count_lengths(text):

    up_to_three = 0  
    four_or_five = 0 
    six_to_nine = 0  
    ten_or_more = 0  
    newtext = text.split(' ')

def main():

    filename = "gb.txt"
    text = readfile(filename)
    word_lengths = count_lengths(text)
    print(word_lengths)
```

After converting the .txt file to a list, I'm pretty lost. Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest would be to use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter

text = 'Some text from your file that you have read into this variable'

    print(sorted(map(len, text.split())))

    word_lengths = {}

    # cumulate number of words
    total = 0
    for k,v in sorted(Counter(map(len, text.split())).items()):
        total += v
        word_lengths[k] = total


    print(word_lengths)
    # {8: 12, 3: 1, 4: 11}
```

Comment: you know better :P you need to sort first :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks. Soring added

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.Counter` will yield a `dict`-like object with the keys as word lengths and values as number of words at each length.

```
>>> s = 'hello this is a sentence with words of varying lengths'
```

First, keep track of all the word lengths:

```
>>> lengths = [len(word) for word in s.split()]
>>> lengths
[5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 7]
```

Then, count how many words occur in the string above at varying lengths:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word_lengths = Counter(lengths)
>>> word_lengths
Counter({2: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 7: 2, 1: 1, 8: 1})
```

Edit: Since you want a cumulative sum, try this:

```
def count_lengths(text, n):
    lengths = [len(word) for word in text.split()]
    word_lengths = Counter(lengths)
    # count the total number of words with lengths less than or equal to n
    n_and_less_chars = sum(value for key, value in word_lengths.items() if key <= n)
    return n_and_less_chars
```

Trying it out:

```
>>> print(count_lengths(s, 5))
7
```

If we look at the example string above, we can see that there are, in fact, 7 words with 5 characters or less.

Comment: OPs wants cumulative sum, i.e., there is 5 words with length 5 or less.